# FFMPEG: Error writing trailer of v%v/index.m3u8: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ffmpeg

I wanted to convert one video track and 2 audio tracks to HLS by combining them.
That means, the HLS conversion has to be multi-bitrate and multi-language both.

**What do I want to achieve?**
I have to prepare an HLS stream for 3 resolutions, namely, 720px, 480px and 360px.
Also, there will be 2 audio tracks in the resultant stream, one English and another Hindi.
I am running the below command and getting the error as described below.
Can anybody help me out?

**Command:**

```
ffmpeg-5.0.1-amd64-static/ffmpeg -i raw/vid_only.mp4 -i raw/english.mp3 -i raw/hindi.mp3 \
-c:a:0 aac \
-c:a:1 aac \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]split=3[v1][v2][v3]; \
[v1]scale=w=1280:h=720[v1out]; [v2]scale=w=854:h=480[v2out]; [v3]scale=w=640:h=360[v3out]" \
-map [v1out] -c:v:0 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:0 5M -maxrate:v:0 5M -minrate:v:0 5M -bufsize:v:0 10M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map [v2out] -c:v:1 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:1 3M -maxrate:v:1 3M -minrate:v:1 3M -bufsize:v:1 3M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map [v3out] -c:v:2 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:2 1M -maxrate:v:2 1M -minrate:v:2 1M -bufsize:v:2 1M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map 1:a -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k -ac 2 \
-map 1:a -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 96k -ac 2 \
-map 1:a -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 48k -ac 2 \
-map 2:a -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k -ac 2 \
-map 2:a -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 96k -ac 2 \
-map 2:a -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 48k -ac 2 \
-var_stream_map "a:0,agroup:audio,default:yes a:1,agroup:audio v:0,agroup:audio" \
-var_stream_map "v:0,name:720p v:1,name:480p v:2,name:360p" v%v/index.m3u8 \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
-f hls \
-hls_time 6 \
-hls_list_size 0 \
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_flags independent_segments \
-hls_segment_type mpegts \
-hls_segment_filename v%v/data%02d.ts \
-max_muxing_queue_size 80072 \
-muxing_queue_data_threshold 30036
```

**Output:**

```
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Unable to find mapping variant stream00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x    
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Unable to find mapping variant stream
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Unable to find mapping variant stream
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Unable to find mapping variant stream
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Unable to find mapping variant stream
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Unable to find mapping variant stream
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Cannot allocate memory
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Unable to find mapping variant stream
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Opening 'v720p/index0.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Opening 'v720p/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Opening 'v480p/index0.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Opening 'v480p/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Opening 'v360p/index0.ts' for writing
[hls @ 0x59c3340] Opening 'v360p/index.m3u8.tmp' for writing
Error writing trailer of v%v/index.m3u8: Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: Please use the appropriate code tags for output and code.